# jQuery - Use a "for-each" loop to change variables outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, var

I have two variables say:

```
var first = "first";
var second = "second";
```

that I would like to change using an $.each loop:

```
$.each({first, second}, function(index, value) {
    value = "changed";  // ASSUME CREATES A NEW VARIABLE?
});

console.log(first);   // DOES NOT CHANGE
console.log(second);  // DOES NOT CHANGE
```

Is this possible? My attempts so far do not seem to produce the desired results; each variable should be changed to  "changed".

EDIT: The goal is to loop over "var first" and "var second" and change their value to "changed" in order to avoid:

```
var first = "first";
var second = "second";

first = "changed";
second = "changed";
```

The actual usage scenario without the loop would result in multiple `first = "changed"` and `second = "changed"` lines of code that I want to avoid.

EDIT #2: Here is an actual snippet of code.

```
var favorite_array = [
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{account_id}/favorite/movies?api_key=",
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{account_id}/favorite/tv?api_key=",
];

var watchlist_array = [
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{account_id}/watchlist/movies?api_key=",
    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{account_id}/watchlist/tv?api_key=",
];

var fquery = (type == "tv") ? favorite_array[1] : favorite_array[0];
var wquery = (type == "tv") ? watchlist_array[1] : watchlist_array[0];


$.each(["fquery", "wquery"], function(index, query) {
    window[query] = window[query].replace("{account_id}", getCookie("account_id"));
    window[query] += api_key + language + "&session_id=";
});
```

I will apologize ahead of time, JavaScript is not my jam.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Please give us more context, maybe there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir In my usage scenario I'm creating a function that will have multiple JSON queries that the request (url) needs to be built up before doing the query. There are two queries that need to happen and both requests (url) need to be built. So instead of having a chain of replace or += statements I was trying to do this in a loop using jQuery $.each. The question is rather generic incase someone else is looking to do something similar.

Comment: Can you provide an example code of what you've just said? BTW this might work if you're using an object instead of separate variables.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How's that?

Comment: Can you group the variables into one big object instead of making them separate? Is `var myVariables = { first: "first", second: "second" }` instead of `var first = "first", second = "second";` ok?

Comment: I could, but was trying to keep it simple.

Comment: As it stands now, you can't because strings, being primitive values, are copied instead of passed around as references. The only way is to group them into an object. BTW this is still an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that can be solved in an entirely different way (I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve).

Comment: You can just do: `first = second = "changed";` to set them both to the same value.

Comment: @Paulpro the actual usage scenario is that I have 15 starting variables

Comment: You can do that with fifteen.

Comment: Isn't your goal just to specify "changed" only once? That would be the most concise way to do that.

Comment: If you have more than one variable representing similar data you should probably be using an array instead of a bunch of variables though. That would make your looping version work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Really do not understand that why are you doing this.

But, this may help for what you are trying to do:

```
var first = "first";
var second = "second";
$.each(["first", "second"], function(index, value) {
  window[value] = "changed";
});
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

I really suggest you to use objects OR arrays instead.

Please check @ CodePen:
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/ebdb516cb0c3e728a054ba45b415c17f/

---

UPDATE:

To make it more automated, I suggested you to start all variables for example with "my_". Please check:

```
// Use something more unique than my_

var my_first = "first";
var my_second = "second";

for (var key in window) if (key.substr(0, 3) == "my_") window[key] = "changed";

console.log(my_first);
console.log(my_second);
```

That one single line will set all variables starting with "my_" to "changed", no matter how many variables you have.

Please check @ CodePen
https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/2de7386d83f27945c82e301982901310

---

UPDATE:

Simplest will be to use @Paulpro's suggestion to use:
`first = second = "changed";`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question to reflect the why.

Comment: @artomason: No problem my friend. Please upvote my answer if I could help.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the window[value] part of your answer.

Comment: @artomason: In your code when you are passing the first & second variables to the $.each function, only variable values are passed and it does not hold the actual variables' references. So, I modified it to pass variable names instead of variable value. Any variable created can also be referenced from the global window object. So, when you defined first & second objects, they are stored in the window and now you can actually reference them using window["first"] or window["second"] too.

Comment: @artomason: I have added one more solution and updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having issues getting it too work. Actual code snippet above under Edit #2.

Comment: @artomason: Can you tell me the issue you are facing?

Comment: When I run that code under EDIT #2 I get `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference`. If I comment out the `.replace` code I don't get the error, but the variables don't update with the `api_key` and `language` strings that I'm adding

Comment: @artomason: Also, I think @Paulpro's idea about `first = second = "changed";` will be much easier for you.

Comment: @artomason: In your Edit #2, where you are doing `window[query].replace`, please note that `window[query]` will be null/undefined in that case, because it is inside a function and not a root variable. So, please use query.replace instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're creating a temporary object with `{first, second}`, so when you're changing the value inside, the actual variables `first` and `second` are not chaning, rather the values inside that object is changing.

So you have to first store it as a variable, then `console.log` the `variable[index]`.

But that will not work properly here since that variable is not an array. `$.each()` works with arrays.

So you have to turn that into an array instead.